# Dynamic "string" in R

Tags: sql, r, rodbc

Simple question, but cannot find the answer.

Instead of:

```
Df <- sqlQuery(ch, "SELECT * FROM tblTest WHERE Id=25")
```

I want a more dynamic piece of code. Something like:

```
Id <- 25
Df <- sqlQuery(ch, c("SELECT * FROM tblTest WHERE Id=", Id))
```

But this is not correct.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We can use paste:

```
Df <- sqlQuery(ch, paste("SELECT * FROM tblTest WHERE Id =", Id))
```

`c` concatenates into a vector, `paste` is for string concatenation.

Or we can use sprintf:

```
sprintf("SELECT * FROM tblTest WHERE Id = %s", Id)
```

Answer (score 2):

Just want to update this with a more modern answer using dplyr/tidyverse which uses string interpolation via the `str_glue` command:

```
str_glue("SELECT * FROM tblTest WHERE Id = {Id}")
```

You can put any expression you want in there. For example, if you wanted to select multiple Id's using a vector:

```
str_glue("SELECT * FROM tblTest WHERE Id IN ({str_c(id_vector, collapse = \",\"})")
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have multiple or reused arguments and a query that contains % you can use something like the following:

```
sprintf("SELECT * FROM test WHERE id = %1$s AND name = %2$s and type like ‘%%tall%%’”, id, name)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `glue_sql()`. Example:

```
Id <- 25

Df <- sqlQuery(ch, glue_sql("SELECT * FROM tblTest WHERE Id= {Id}", .con = ch))
```

More info [here](https://glue.tidyverse.org/#glue_sql-makes-constructing-sql-statements-safe-and-easy).