# Add a dynamic value into RMySQL getQuery

Tags: r, rmysql

Is it possible to pass a value into the query in `dbGetQuery` from the RMySQL package.

For example, if I have a set of values in a character vector:

```
df <- c('a','b','c')
```

And I want to loop through the values to pull out a specific value from a database for each.

```
library(RMySQL)    
res <- dbGetQuery(con, "SELECT max(ID) FROM table WHERE columna='df[2]'")
```

When I try to add the reference to the value I get an error. Wondering if it is possible to add a value from an R object in the query.

Comment: Duplicate of [RSQLite query with user specified variable in the WHERE field](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3449666/271616)

Comment: Joshua, thanks for pointing that out. that is a great answer also. I had been searching for RMySQL solutions.

Comment: the solution is the same whether you're using RMySQL or RSQLlite.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option is to manipulate the SQL string within the loop. At the moment you have a string literal, the `'df[2]'` is not interpreted by R as anything other than characters. There are going to be some ambiguities in my answer, because `df` in your Q is patently not a data frame (it is a character vector!). Something like this will do what you want.

Store the output in a numeric vector:

```
require(RMySQL)
df <- c('a','b','c')
out <- numeric(length(df))
names(out) <- df
```

Now we can loop over the elements of `df` to execute your query three times. We can set the loop up two ways: i) with `i` as a number which we use to reference the elements of `df` and `out`, or ii) with `i` as each element of `df` in turn (i.e. `a`, then `b`, ...). I will show both versions below.

```
## Version i
for(i in seq_along(df)) {
    SQL <- paste("SELECT max(ID) FROM table WHERE columna='", df[i], "';", sep = "")
    out[i] <- dbGetQuery(con, SQL)
    dbDisconnect(con)
}
```

OR:

```
## Version ii
for(i in df) {
    SQL <- paste("SELECT max(ID) FROM table WHERE columna='", i, "';", sep = "")
    out[i] <- dbGetQuery(con, SQL)
    dbDisconnect(con)
}
```

Which you use will depend on personal taste. The second (ii) version requires you to set names on the output vector `out` that are the same as the data inside `out`.

Having said all that, assuming your actual SQL Query is similar to the one you post, can't you do this in a single SQL statement, using the `GROUP BY` clause, to group the data before computing `max(ID)`? Doing simple things in the data base like this will likely be much quicker. Unfortunately, I don't have a MySQL instance around to play with and my SQL-fu is weak currently, so I can't given an example of this.

Comment: @Gavin, off the top of my head, I think the query you mention in your last paragraph would be: `SELECT max(ID), columna FROM table WHERE columna in ('a','b','c') GROUP BY columna`

Comment: Remembering of course to make sure you don't have anything that can break SQL syntax in your variable. Obligatory XKCD reference: http://xkcd.com/327/

Comment: @Spacedman, Little Bobby Tables... classic!

Comment: Thank you for the detail in your post. It is very helpful and, once again, I learned quite a bit from it. Regarding the need for a GROUP BY clause in my SQL Statement, because this ID is a numeric auto-incrementer and primary key there can only be distinct values in that column so I don't need a GROUP BY.

Comment: @analyticsPierce: I think you miss the point of the `GROUP BY`. What I was thinking, and Joshua Ulrich put into SQL for us, is that you could return a data frame with the 3 `max(ID)` values in one column and the `columna` (`a`,`b`,`c`) in the second column, from a **single** SQL statement. So no need to do the three SQL statements in a loop. Do the one statement, get the DB to do the work, and then pull out the values you want on the R side. That is far less effort, typing, and compute time.

Comment: ok, I understand your example now. My question is simplified from the full problem I am trying to solve. Here is a summary of the bigger issue: I have a db table with a set of keywords, each keyword has a set of rows associated to it. Each of these rows has a numeric ID. I am trying to query an API (has to be done one keyword at a time) and return a data.frame of results. Then I need to insert the rows into the db table where the ID is > than IDs already in the table. I understand your point but struggling with the right structure in R and I am not able to add a string into dbGetQuery.

Comment: I did get the paste function figured out so I could create the queries properly. that's handy stuff.

Answer (score 3):

You could also use the `sprintf` command to solve the issue (it's what I use when building Shiny Apps).

`df <- c('a','b','c')`

`res <- dbGetQuery(con, sprintf("SELECT max(ID) FROM table WHERE columna='%s'"),df())`

Something along those lines should work.