# Pass R variable to RODBC's sqlQuery with multiple entries?

Tags: r

I'm in the process of learning R, to wave SAS goodbye, I'm still new to this and I somehow have difficulties finding exactly what I'm looking for.

But for this specific case, I read:
[Pass R variable to RODBC's sqlQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4330072/pass-r-variable-to-rodbcs-sqlquery)
and made it work for myself, as long as I'm only inserting one variable in the destination table.

Here is my code:

```
library(RODBC)
channel <- odbcConnect("test")
b <- sqlQuery(channel,
  "select top 1 Noinscr
   FROM table
   where PrixVente > 100
   order by datevente desc")

sqlQuery(channel,
   paste("insert into TestTable (UniqueID) Values (",b,")", sep = "")
```

When I replace the `top 1` by any other number, let's say `top 2`, and run the exact same code, I get the following errors:

```
[1] "42000 195 [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0][SQL Server]
    'c' is not a recognized built-in function name."      
[2] "[RODBC] ERROR: Could not SQLExecDirect 
    'insert into TestTable  (UniqueID) Values (c(8535735, 8449336))'"
```

I understand that it is because there is an extra c that is generated, I assume for column when I give the command: `paste(b)`.

So how can I get `"8535735, 8449336"` instead of `"c(8535735, 8449336)"` when using `paste(b)`?  Or is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look into the `collapse` argument in the `paste()` documentation.  Try replacing `b` with `paste(b, collapse = ", ")`, as shown below.

**Edit**  As Joshua points out, sqlQuery returns a data.frame, not a vector. So, instead of `paste(b, collapse = ", ")`, you could use `paste(b[[1]], collapse = ", ")`.

```
library(RODBC)
channel <- odbcConnect("test")
b <- sqlQuery(channel,
  "select top 1 Noinscr
   FROM table
   where PrixVente > 100
   order by datevente desc")

sqlQuery(channel,
   ## note paste(b[[1]], collapse = ", ") in line below
   paste("insert into TestTable (UniqueID) Values (", paste(b[[1]], collapse = ", "),")", sep = "")
```

Comment: And just FYI here is a somewhat more elaborate version, as I did not know the collapse parameter (and was too late answering): `Reduce(function(u, v) paste(u, ", ", v, sep=""), b)`

Comment: Added the [[1]] and it works like a charm! the c(  ) is gone!

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `b` looks like this:

```
b <- data.frame(Noinscr=c("8535735", "8449336"))
```

Then you only need a couple steps:

```
# in case Noinscr is a factor
b$Noinscr <- as.character(b$Noinscr)
# convert the vector into a single string
# NOTE that I subset to get the vector, since b is a data.frame
B <- paste(b$Noinscr, collapse=",")
# create your query
paste("insert into TestTable (UniqueID) Values (",B,")", sep="")
# [1] "insert into TestTable (UniqueID) Values (8535735,8449336)"
```

You got odd results because `sqlQuery` returns a `data.frame`, not a vector.  As you learned, using `paste` on a data.frame (or any list) can provide weird results because `paste` must return a character vector.

Comment: I still run into an error, this time, I assume its because I transformed it into text and trying to put back text in a sql field that is a float. now I get the following error:   cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'character'

Comment: @Felixthecat: I doubt that's it because `paste` is going to convert `b$Noinscr` to a character vector even if it were a numeric or integer vector.  The error most likely means you're trying to convert a function to a character vector.  Check your syntax carefully.

Comment: @Felixthecat: To troubleshoot, could you post the output of `print(b)` in your question?