# Execute multiple SQL statements at the same time with RODBC

Tags: sql, r, rodbc

I have a fairly complex SQL query that I am trying to run through RODBC that involves defining variables. A simplified version looks like this:

```
DECLARE @VARX CHAR = 'X';
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE TYPE = @VARX;
```

Running this code works just fine. This fails:

```
library(RODBC)
q <- "DECLARE @VARX CHAR = 'X';\nSELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE TYPE = @VARX;"
sqlQuery(ch, q)
# returns character(0)
```

I have found through experimentation that the first statement before the semicolon is executed, but the rest is not. Is there a way to execute the full query?

I'm using SQL server by the way.

**EDIT** This was marked as a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8127718/pass-r-variable-to-rodbcs-sqlquery-with-multiple-entries) question, but they are asking completely different things. In this question I would like to execute a script that contains multiple statements, and in the other the author is only trying to execute a single statement.