# Pass object to python SQL

Tags: python, mysql, pandas, pyodbc

I have a pandas df pulled from an ODBC connection:

```
import pandas.io.sql as psql
handle = pyodbc.connect('...')
df1 = psql.frame_query("select * from Table1 where... [some queries on columns]")
# below is a pandas df resulting from the above SQL query
df1 = pd.DataFrame([[1, 'F', 11111, 500, 60], [2, 'M', 22222, 400, 30], [3, 'M', 33333, 5400, 78], [4, 'F', 44444, 5400, 45], [5, 'M', 55555, 8914, 66]], columns = ['ID','Gender','ZipCd','Spend','Age'])
```

Now I want to run a separate query on a different table in the same database; and as one of the criteria, extract rows that match the IDs from `df1` (e.g. below, which does not work).

```
df2 = psql.frame_query("select * from Table2 where ID = ? and StatusCd in ('104', '106', '112', '115')", df1['ID'])
# The ID variable is a common unique identifier b/n the 2 tables
```

My question is, how do I assign `df1['ID']` as a list of elements to query in `df2`? e.g. `...where ID in (1,2,3,...)`, but using df1['ID'] as an object containing the list. This would return records where IDs in df2 matched those of df1 as well as the other query criteria.

I am familiar w/ R syntax, so conceptually, my question very closely resembles this one: [Pass R variable to RODBC's sqlQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4330072/pass-r-variable-to-rodbcs-sqlquery)

At the end of the day, I'm interested in parsing down table 1 so that it includes only records found in table 2 (i.e. that have one of the requisite StatusCds found in table 2). In this respect, I'm certain there is a more efficient way to call in the data, and probably in one query, but I'm not literate enough in python or SQL yet.

## Further comment

I have pyodbc as a tag since i was originally pulling from my SQL servers using that module; maybe pyodbc is the more efficient method to use for this kind of task? But I'm an R/spreadsheet guy & pandas has just been the easiest thing for me to learn so far.

Comment: `df1[ID]` is a column. Do you want separate queries for each element, one query for all of the elements, or a single query for 1 of the elements?

Comment: @PaulH if you're referring to how `df1['ID']` should be treated, i believe i am looking for one query for all/any of the elements in df1$ID. i have edited my post accordingly on your question.

Comment: possible duplicate of ["Large data" work flows using pandas](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14262433/large-data-work-flows-using-pandas)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`frame_query` accepts an optional `params` keyword argument that can be a list or tuple of parameters to use in the SQL query. To be able to include a list of parameters, you can use python's string formatting to include the right number of placeholders.

For example:

```
placeholders = ','.join(['?'] * df1['ID'].count())
query = ("select * from Table2 where ID in ({}) "
         "and StatusCd in ('104', '106', '112', '115')").format(placeholders)
df2 = psql.frame_query(query, params=df1['ID'].tolist())
```

The query string would be `select * from Table2 where ID in (?, ?, ?) and StatusCd in ('104', '106', '112', '115')` if there are three IDs.

There is a limit on the number of parameters you can send, so if you have a very large number you might want to do a number of queries in batches and then concatenate the resulting DataFrames.

Comment: I don't know... I have about 100K+ IDs to search on. seems like it would be a lot of `?`s

Comment: I'm afraid that is the only way to include `df1['ID']` in the query, since pyodbc will not know what to do with the Series. You also have to use `ID in (...)` because the Series is the equivalent to an array. As I mentioned you can split it into a number of different queries if there are too many IDs, or if the IDs represent a significant proportion of the total rows in the table, then query the entire table and join the resulting DataFrames. Which is the best solution (single query with many parameters vs multiple queries vs whole table) depends on your data, so you will need to experiment .

Answer (score 0):

Use an `INNER JOIN` in your original query to return rows from `table1` with matching IDs in `table2` for the status codes you need. While you're at it, put the status codes in a variable and parameterize the SQL statement execution. Code would look something like this:

```
...
codes = ("104", "106", "112", "115")
sql = """select Table1.*
         from Table1
         inner join Table2
            on Table1.ID = Table2.ID
         where Table2.StatusCd in (?, ?, ?, ?)"""
df1 = psql.frame_query(sql, codes)
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer to this lies in constructing a better SQL query:

```
psql.frame_query("select... from Table1 as t1
                 inner join Table 2 t2
                 on t1.ID = t2.ID
                 where [add various queries from both tables]", handle)
```

Moving to close this post since it's more appropriately a SQL question & answered with basic documentation.