# Joining, merging or selecting object from an SQL database based on R dataframe

Tags: r, sql-server, odbc, rodbc

I have a sample drawn with the strata function in package sampling and would like further information about the sampled object's, in an SQL database. I have tried both RODBC and odbc packages without any smooth soloution.

example:

```
test<-sqlQuery("con", paste("select * from table",
                            "where table.ID=df.ID"))
```

What is the appropriate method without having to write a new table in the database?

Comment: Relevant, possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/4330072/680068

Comment: We are trying to pass R variable into SQL query, see linked posts for examples, let us know if it doesn't help, I will re-open.