# R dbGetQuery with dynamic string

Tags: sql, r, sqlite, rsqlite

From [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3416973/dynamic-string-in-r) and [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3449666/rsqlite-query-with-user-specified-variable-in-the-where-field), I got a way to write an rsqlite dynamic command. However, it doesn't work for me. My data looks like:

```
Id <- c(34, 22, 86)
sqlcmd <- paste("select col1, col2 from DB where ItemId =", Id, sep="")
Df <- dbGetQuery(conn, sqlcmd)
```

My `sqlcmd` gives me a list of strings as

```
"select col1, col2 from DB where STOREID =34"
"select col1, col2 from DB where STOREID =22"
"select col1, col2 from DB where STOREID =86"
```

However, when I pass `sqlcmd` to `dbGetQuery`, it only returns data with `ItemId = 34`, which is the first element in the `Id` list.

I'm wondering if anyone has any ideas on why does this happen? Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: `dbGetQuery` only returns first statement (multiple resultset is not implemented  yet). So, you need to iteratively run it for multiple SQL statements. Otherwise use a `UNION` for one SQL statement.

Comment: Regardless of your preferred answer: (1) *please* do not use `paste("select...",Id2)`, you are open to [sql injection](https://xkcd.com/327/), better to use `sqlInterpolate`, `dbQuoteString`, or `dbBind`; (2) it is usually (much) faster/cheaper to do `select id,col1,col2 ... where id in (11,12,13)` and use `split()` or similar in R than to do three round-trip queries, esp with larger data; (3) if you are thinking of using `union`, then you might as well stick with `...where id in (11,12,13)` in a single query without `union` ... if order matters, then be explicit about the preferred order.

Comment: http://db.rstudio.com/best-practices/run-queries-safely/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since I believe R DBI drivers have not yet implemented multiple SQL statements support, `dbGetQuery` only returns first statement.

Hence, you need to iteratively run your *sqlcmd* for multiple SQL statements such as with `lapply` to return a list of dataframes, followed by an `rbind` call for single master dataframe:

```
Id <- c(34, 22, 86)
sqlcmd <- paste("select col1, col2 from DB where ItemId =", Id, sep="")

# LIST OF DATAFRAMES
df_list <- lapply(sqlcmd , function(x) dbGetQuery(conn, x)) 

# FINAL DATAFRAME
final_df <- do.call(rbind, df_list)
```

Alternatively, use a `UNION` or `UNION ALL` for one SQL statement.

```
Id <- c(34, 22, 86)
sqlcmd <- paste("select col1, col2 from DB where ItemId =", Id, sep="")

single_sql <- paste(sqlcmd, collapse = " UNION ")
final_df <- dbGetQuery(conn, single_sql)
```

Or still use `OR`:

```
single_sql <- paste("select col1, col2 from DB where ItemId =", 
                    paste(Id, collapse=" OR ItemId = "))

final_df <- dbGetQuery(conn, single_sql)
```

Comment: Hi Parfait, thank you for the answer! I end up with using the OR method. Much appreciated!

Comment: Great! Glad to help. Happy coding!

Answer (score 2):

This also works with parametrized queries:

```r
library(RSQLite)
conn <- dbConnect(SQLite())
dbWriteTable(conn, "DB", data.frame(col1 = 1, col2 = 2, ItemId = 3))

Id <- c(34, 22, 86)
sqlcmd <- "select col1, col2 from DB where ItemId = ?"
Df <- dbGetQuery(conn, sqlcmd, params = list(Id))
```

> Created on 2018-06-11 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Recent versions of *DBI* and *RSQLite* will return a data frame that contains the results from these queries concatenated.

Comment: Hey Krlmlr, really appreciate for  your help! When I'm trying this approach, R returns an error massage as  ERROR:  pg_atoi: error in "c(34, 22, 86)": can't parse "c(34, 22, 86)". Do you have any idea about why does this happen?

Comment: @Mr369: I've expanded the example to make it self-contained, works for me. Can you run the code as is?

Answer (score 1):

I would normally do this like this:

```
Id1 <- c(34, 22, 86)

Id2 <- paste(Id1, collapse = ", ")
sqlcmd <- paste("select col1, col2 from DB where ItemId in (", Id2, ")", sep="")
Df <- dbGetQuery(conn, sqlcmd)
```

However if you want to return a list of data frames for each id and run the query three times you could do:

```
sqlcmd <- paste("select col1, col2 from DB where ItemId in (", Id1, ")", sep="")    
dataList <- lapply(sqlcmd, function(x) dbGetQuery(conn, x))
```

Answer (score 1):

Just noting that using variables in a SQL query is generally discouraged, as it can make you susceptible to an injection attack. https://db.rstudio.com/best-practices/run-queries-safely/