# How to use glue_data_sql to write safe parameterized queries on an SQL server database?

Tags: r, sql-server, r-dbi

**The problem**

I want to write a wrapper around some `DBI` functions that allows safe execution of parameterized queries. I've found the [this resource](https://db.rstudio.com/best-practices/run-queries-safely/#using-glue_sql) that explains how to use the `glue` package to insert parameters into an SQL query. However, there seem to be two distinct ways to use the `glue` package to insert parameters:

1. **Method 1** involves using `?` in the sql query where the parameters need to be inserted, and then subsequently using `dbBind` to fill them in. Example from the link above:

```
library(glue)
library(DBI)

airport_sql <- glue_sql("SELECT * FROM airports WHERE faa = ?")
airport <- dbSendQuery(con, airport_sql)

dbBind(airport, list("GPT"))
dbFetch(airport)
```

2. **Method 2** involves using `glue_sql` or `glue_data_sql` to fill in the parameters by itself (no use of `dbBind`). Again an example from the link above:

```
airport_sql <- 
  glue_sql(
    "SELECT * FROM airports WHERE faa IN ({airports*})", 
    airports = c("GPT", "MSY"),
    .con = con
  )

airport <- dbSendQuery(con, airport_sql)

dbFetch(airport)
```

I would prefer using the second method because this has a lot of extra functionality such as collapsing multiple values for an `in` statement in the `where` clause of an sql statement. See second example above for how that works (note the `*` after the parameter which indicates it must be collapsed). The question is: is this safe against SQL injection? (Are there other things I need to worry about?)

**My code**

This is currently the code I have for my wrapper.

```
paramQueryWrapper <- function(
  sql,
  params = NULL,
  dsn    = standard_dsn,
  login  = user_login,
  pw     = user_pw
){

  if(missing(sql) || length(sql) != 1 || !is.character(sql)){
    stop("Please provide sql as a character vector of length 1.")
  }

  if(!is.null(params)){
    if(!is.list(params))       stop("params must be a (named) list (or NULL).")
    if(length(params) < 1)     stop("params must be either NULL, or contain at least one element.")
    if(is.null(names(params)) || any(names(params) == "")) stop("All elements in params must be named.")
  }

  con <- DBI::dbConnect(
    odbc::odbc(),
    dsn      = dsn,
    UID      = login,
    PWD      = pw
  )
  on.exit(DBI::dbDisconnect(con), add = TRUE)


  # Replace params with corresponding values and execute query

  sql <- glue::glue_data_sql(.x = params, sql, .con = con)

  query <- DBI::dbSendQuery(conn = con, sql)
  on.exit(DBI::dbClearResult(query), add = TRUE, after = FALSE)

  return(tibble::as_tibble(DBI::dbFetch(query)))

}
```

**My question**

Is this safe against SQL injection? Especially since I am not using `dbBind`.

**Epilogue**

I know that there already exists a wrapper called `dbGetQuery` that allows parameters (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50767089/r-dbgetquery-with-dynamic-string) for more info - look for the answer by @krlmlr for an example with a parameterized query). But this again relies on the first method using `?` which is much more basic in terms of functionality.

Comment: I see SQL injection mentioned in the `DBI` documentation: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/DBI/DBI.pdf

Comment: `glue_sql` documentation also mentions injection (on top of `dbBind`): https://glue.tidyverse.org/reference/glue_sql.html

Comment: @MichaelChirico 1. About the `DBI` documentation. This mentions SQL injection in several functions amongst which `dbBind`. But as I have mentioned in my answer this function does not allow named parameters for an SQL server database. So unless someone can explain to me how to use `dbBind` with named parameters on sql server this is irrelevant. 2. About the documentation on `glue_sql`. This literally only says parameterized queries are safest, implying that use of `dbBind` is better. But it doesn't mention anything about the safety of using `glue_sql` by itself. Again not answering my question.

Comment: Looking at [this tweet](https://twitter.com/klmr/status/913742759844040704), it seems that `glue_sql` in principle is not safe against SQL injection